# Are these proofs of two Halting Problems rigorous?

Tags: solution-verification, computability

I apologize if this question is more suited for CS Stack Exchange, but since my question is primarily about *rigor* rather than the Halting Problem in particular, I felt like this is a place to post it.

My reference for the first proof are from [these excellent slides](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse311/18au/doc/lecture28.pdf) (p. 32).

Firstly, two definitions. For any program `P`, `code(P)` is `P` in string format. For any program `P`, `H(code(P), a)` returns true if and only if the instance `P(a)` halts. Now, consider the following program in C syntax:

```
void D(string x) {
    if (H(x, x) == true) {
        while (true);
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Now the proof of the impossibility of `H` existing follows immediately. `D(code(D))` either halts or it does not.

1. It halts, which means that `H(code(D), code(D))` returns true. But by the definition of `D`, this means that `D(code(D))` does not halt (we fall into the first branch which leads into an infinite loop).
2. It does not halt, which means that `H(code(D), code(D))` returns false. But by the definition of `D`, this means that `D(code(D))` halts (we fall into the second branch which leads immediately to a `return` statement).

This seems pretty formal and satisfactory to me, but I have doubts since the more mathematical exposition of the Halting Problem which I read was much more complicated and incomprehensible to me. Am I missing something?

If we consider programs with $2$ or more parameters, the argument is almost exactly the same. More interesting is the case of a halting function which decides whether a program with zero parameters halts.

We can consider this program:

```
void D() {
    if (H(x) == true) {
       while (true);
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

and try substituting `code(D)` for the free variable `x`. But here the problem arises. If we do that, we have changed `D` itself, which means that it isn't `code(D)` we are substituting into `D` in the first place! Let me know if the following fix succeeds:

We consider two programs:

```
void A() {
    if (H(code(B)) == true) {
       while (true);
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}

void B() {
    A();
}
```

`A()` either halts or it does not.

1. It halts, which means that `B()` halts, which means that `H(code(B))` returns true. But by the definition of `A`, this means that `A()` does not halt (as before, we fall into the first branch).
2. It does not halt, which means that `B()` does not halt, which means that `H(code(B))` returns false. But by the definition of `A`, this means that `A()` halts (as before, we fall into the second branch).

I do not really doubt the correctness of these results, but I am concerned about their possible lack of rigor. I would appreciate feedback about their correctness and formality, and also an explanation why the mathematical version of the Halting Problem is much more complicated. Thank you. :)

P.S. This is a response to spaceisdarkgreen's excellent answer.

I tried making his suggestions concrete. So, consider the following function:

```
void DHasCodeD() {
    if (H(code(D), code(D)) == true) {
        while (true);
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

The halting problem now transfers over to the program `D(x)`. This answers my initial question: supposing that `H(x, y)` exists, we can also derive a contradiction from a zero-parameter function.

However, what's bugging me here is that we are using a halting oracle with two parameters. We have not shown that `H(x)` does not exist. After all, what if `H(x)` is weaker than `H(x, y)`?

We try the following:

```
DZero() {
    if (H(code(DHasCodeD)) == true) {
        while (true);
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

The proof by contradiction transfers again. But in my mind, this proof is problematic because it *presupposes* the existence of a halting oracle with two parameters. To be convinced, I would have to see a proof by contradiction involving only `H(x)`.

Comment: each of the three instances of "else {return;}" are redundant fluff that should be removed for clarity.

Comment: The way you have presented these proofs are unnacceptable levels of rigour. You need to use sentences like "Suppose we have a computable function $H$ that, ...". Instead what you have written "H returns true" - this is unamibiguous and yeah as you have it written here these are not rigorous arguments. You have the gist though your vocabulary should be far more specific to the situation at hand, instead you are using several assumptions when writing just a single sentence of definitions here.

Comment: @Snared I disagree. Even though the programs would be semantically correct without that piece of code, I left them in to illustrate the point of the program terminating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we let $halt_1:S_1 \times \Sigma^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ denote the halting function for programs with one input. Here $S_1$ is a suitable subset of $\Sigma^*$ denoting all syntactically correct programs (with one input). So given any two strings $s \in S_1$ and $t \in \Sigma^*$ we say that $halt_1(s,t)=1$ iff the program with code $s$ halts when given the input $t$. We say that $halt_1(s,t)=0$ iff the program with code $s$ does not halt when given the input $t$.

The first point is that there is no program that takes on two input strings and computes the function $Halt_1:\Sigma^* \times \Sigma^* \rightarrow \{0,1,2\}$. In other words:

> $Halt_1:\Sigma^* \times \Sigma^* \rightarrow \{0,1,2\}$ is not a (total) computable function.

Here we have $Halt_1(i,j)=halt_1(i,j)$ for all $i \in S_1$ and $j \in \Sigma^*$. However, when $i \notin S_1$ and $j \in \Sigma^*$ we have $Halt_1(i,j)=2$.

---

Now using the result in previous paragraph we can show several more results. First of all consider the function $halt_0:S_0 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. Here $S_0$ is a suitable subset of $\Sigma^*$ denoting all syntactically correct programs with no input. So given a string $s \in S_0$ we say that $halt_0(s)=1$ iff the program with code $s$ halts. We say that $halt_0(s)=0$ iff the program with code $s$ does not halt.

Now consider a function $Halt_0:\Sigma^* \rightarrow \{0,1,2\}$. Here we have $Halt_0(i)=halt_0(i)$ for all $i \in S_0$. However, when $i \notin S_0$ we have $Halt_1(i)=2$.

Now using the fact that $Halt_1:\Sigma^* \times \Sigma^* \rightarrow \{0,1,2\}$ is not a (total) computable function we can show that $Halt_0:\Sigma^* \rightarrow \{0,1,2\}$ is not a (total) computable function. This is shown by the usual "reduction". We first **suppose** that $Halt_0:\Sigma^* \rightarrow \{0,1,2\}$ was a (total) computable function. Then there exists a program that computes $Halt_0:\Sigma^* \rightarrow \{0,1,2\}$. Using the existence of program in previous sentence, we can show that there exists a program that computes the function $Halt_1:\Sigma^* \times \Sigma^* \rightarrow \{0,1,2\}$. However, that would mean that $Halt_1:\Sigma^* \times \Sigma^* \rightarrow \{0,1,2\}$ is computable (which was mentioned above to be false). Therefore our assumption of $Halt_0:\Sigma^* \rightarrow \{0,1,2\}$ being a computable function was incorrect.

---

At the risk of confusing things a bit further, I think there is one more thing to mention. It would happen often that one would not see a distinction between the sets $S_0$ and $S_1$. Instead a single set $S$ will be used. In the latter case, a single program can be thought of as calculating 0-ary,1-ary (2-ary, n-ary etc.) partial computable functions.

Whether such a distinction between $S_0$ and $S_1$ is necessary or not depends on the specific definition of computational model (more specifically, conventions regarding input variables).

Comment: This was a very nice explanation! Thank you very much. For completeness, consider also adding a more "mathematical" proof of the nonexistence of $\mathrm{Halt}_1$. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The first argument looks perfectly fine to me.

The problem with your latter two examples is that the functions aren't self contained... you reference a "free variable" in one and external definitions in the others. A computable function (i.e. the things that we assign code numbers)  is the whole shebang, not just some auxilliary function you might define within a program.

In fact, the slickest way to proceed is to not allow any functions with zero arguments, or with more than one argument, since any computable function of arbitrary arity can be simulated by a computable function with one variable, by ignoring the input in the zero argument case or using a tupling function in the greater-than-one argument case.

But we can still show that the halting problem for zero-argument functions isn't computable, directly from the halting problem for one-argument functions that you proved. The key is that from the code for any one-argument computable function and an argument we want to pass it, we can computably write code for a zero-argument function that does the same thing... we just hardcode the argument and proceed as in the original function.

So if we wanted to tell if a given computable function $f$ halts on input $x$, we could just compute the code the zero-variable function equivalent to the computation of $f(x),$ then pass it into the halting oracle for zero-variable functions. Thus, the halting problem for one-variable functions is reducible to the halting problem for zero-variable functions, so if the former is not computable, neither is the latter.

---

**Edit** As requested, more details.

The crucial thing here is the existence of a computable function that acts like the following python function:

```
def make_zero_argument(input_function, argument):
    def output_function():
       return input_function(argument)
    return output_function
```

only it operates on the *code number* of the input function (in some reasonable numbering of the one-argument computable functions) and returns a *code number* for the output function (in some reasonable numbering of the zero-argument computable functions).

For instance, it takes a code for this function

```
def f(x):
    output = 1
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        output *= i
    return output
```

and the number $10101$ and returns a code for this function

```
def g():
    x = 10101
    output = 1
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        output *= i
    return output
```

It's difficult to write down explicitly (and of course is dependent on the specific model of computation and the choice of numberings), but still is obviously computable given that the numberings are reasonable... e.g. it's obvious what I did to the text of $f$ to get the text of $g$ can be done programmatically. Even though it's not the python function written down above, we'll still call this computable function `make_zero_argument`.

Then we define the one-argument halting function in terms of the zero-argument halting function as follows:

```
def H_1(function_code, input):
    return H_0(make_zero_argument(function_code, input))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added some additional questions to the P.S. section of my question, and I would be very grateful for any help! :)

Comment: @Godbless you have things backwards. My argument shows that if $H(x)$ exists then $H(x,y)$ exists. It presupposes $H(x)$, then constructs $H(x,y)$ from $H(x)$, and since we know $H(x,y)$ doesn’t exist, we have a contradiction from $H(x).$

Comment: I tried carrying out your suggested construction of $H(x, y)$ from $H(x)$ for $D$. However, as outlined in my postscript, the problem is that $D$ already has $H(x, y)$ in its body, so it presupposes its existence. From this, it seems to me that there must be some restriction on the $f$s referred to in your answer.

Comment: I guess that I don't really have a problem with your proof by contradiction, as another user has explicated it nicely and I get it now. What worries me is that I have not been able to construct a concrete paradoxical function `D()` using the suggestion you provided, for the reasons I already stated.

Comment: @Godbless Your attempts above don't make sense to me, and violate my point about functions needing to be self-contained. I added detail and some pseudo-code (hopefully python is okay... first-class functions make the *idea* of the function easy to express, even though, as I note, we really need to be doing some encoding and decoding here, which requires some messy details to write down explicitly).